# Left join with ISNULL condition query taking long time to execute on MySQL RDS

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance-testing, rds, mysqltuner

Kindly help me to optimize below query,this query took more than **60 mints** to execute with the **ISNULL** condition but if we replace **ISNULL** to **<=>** condition its took **15 mints** to execute but our expectation is this query should take maxmimum 2 mints.

Both table have:- 3880494 records.

`SELECT hs.headendid
FROM headendlineups_stagging hs
LEFT JOIN headendlineups_23march2017 hlp ON hs.headendid=hlp.headendid
WHERE ISNULL(hlp.headendid)`

**Replaced ISNULL with <=> operator**

```
SELECT hs.headendid,hlp.headendid AS productionheadend
FROM headendlineups_stagging hs  
LEFT JOIN  headendlineups_23march2017 hlp ON hs.headendid=hlp.headendid
-- WHERE ISNULL(hlp.headendid)
WHERE hlp.headendid <=> NULL;
```

**Explain plain of both queries**

```
**mysql> EXPLAIN
    ->  SELECT hs.headendid
    ->  FROM headendlineups_stagging hs
    ->  LEFT JOIN headendlineups_23march2017 hlp ON hs.headendid=hlp.headendid
    ->  WHERE ISNULL(hlp.headendid)\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: hs
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: IX_lineups_headendid
      key_len: 198
          ref: NULL
         rows: 3854774
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: hlp
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: IX_lineups_headendid,iDX_linups_NEW,New_headends_linup
          key: IX_lineups_headendid
      key_len: 153
          ref: onconnectdb.hs.HeadendId
         rows: 217
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)**


mysql> EXPLAIN
    -> SELECT hs.headendid,hlp.headendid AS productionheadend
    -> FROM headendlineups_stagging hs
    -> LEFT JOIN  headendlineups_23march2017 hlp ON hs.headendid=hlp.headendid
    -> WHERE hlp.headendid <=> NULL\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: hs
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: IX_lineups_headendid
      key_len: 198
          ref: NULL
         rows: 3854774
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: hlp
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: IX_lineups_headendid,iDX_linups_NEW,New_headends_linup
          key: IX_lineups_headendid
      key_len: 153
          ref: onconnectdb.hs.HeadendId
         rows: 217
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Kindly help me to understand if both queries are scanning the same number of records then why the execution time of both queries are different? and kindly suggest the better way of writing above query.

Comment: ISNULL() is a function. Not sure if the query optimizer will manage to understand that as IS NULL, but if not using ISNULL() will force it to execute a function on every returned row.

Comment: peppermints or spearmints?

Answer (score 0):

The difference in time is likely to be caching; run each one again.

Change the `LEFT JOIN` to `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM headendlineups_23march2017 hlp WHERE hs.headendid=hlp.headendid )`  (It might or might not help.

Based on the `EXPLAINs`, it is doing the best it can -- namely `Using index` on both tables.  Face it, you have to scan the entire first table 3.8 million times, then check the second table 3.8 million times.

How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  `SHOW TABLE SIZE` (for each); I want to compare to the buffer pool size.

Comment: I have ** 122 GB**  RAM and `innodb_buffer_pool_size`=90GB , table_size `headendlineups_stagging `=1170 Mb and `headendlineups_23march2017`=1267 Mb

Comment: (OK, no problem with caching.)